# Upgrading Jython from 2.2.1 version to 2.5.2, possible risks

Tags: python, upgrade, jython, backwards-compatibility, jython-2.5

We want to upgrade our version of Jython to 2.5.2. After reading documentation and testing, it seems like the only thing we have to do is to add the encoding `magic comment` in the beginning of each python file, i.e. `#encoding=utf-8`

It seems too easy but I am afraid of possible errors appearing in the future.

Has anyone gone through this? Any backward compatibilities?

Thanks!

Comment: why not install alongside your existing `jython2.2.1` and test it out on your scripts to see if it completely breaks things?

Comment: I changed the interpreter to jython 2.5.2, it compiles and the app works... I am just afraid of things going wrong in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jython 2.5.2 *should have* the functionality of Python 2.5.2.

Doing a quick scan of the [long list of release notes for Python 2.5.2](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.5.2/NEWS.txt), nothing immediately jumps out at me suggesting backwards compatibility is broken. Unless your code relies on the erratic behavior of one of the fixed bugs in the release notes, you should be fine.

My organization recently made the same upgrade (Jython 2.2.1 --> Jython 2.5.2) with no issues.

Some things I noticed while we were upgrading, that are peculiar to Jython:

- `os.chdir` now works on Windows.

  One of our Java packages started (properly) subclassing its `Exception`s as `java.lang.Exception`s in Jython.

If you upgraded the Java runtime your Jython runs under, you should check its release notes as well, especially if your code makes extensive use of the built-in Java packages.